# Strange Behaviour System.NullReferenceException on crosspage postback with Master Page

Tags: c#, exception, nullreferenceexception

I am using C# ASP.NET , i did a crosspage postback and it is working fine, without master page.

But while using Master page , same logic fails and get the error described above. I am new to ASP.NET, please tell me in little detail.

My code  is

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="View_Information.aspx.cs" Inherits="View_Information" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<p>
    Module 3: Assignment 1</p>
<div>
        Total Data You Have Entered
        <br />
        <br />
        Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        Address:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        Thanks for submitting your data.<br />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Placehodler2" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

And code behind is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class View_Information : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (PreviousPage != null && PreviousPage.IsPostBack)
    {
        TextBox nametextpb = (TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("TextBox1");
        //Name of controls should be good to identify in case application is big
        TextBox addresspb = (TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("TextBox2");
        Label1.Text =  nametextpb.Text; //exception were thrown here

        Label2.Text =  addresspb.Text;

    }

    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("Personal_Information.aspx");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where is the exception thrown?

Comment: It is on line 17, Label1.Text =  nametextpb.Text;

Comment: No, Same error , Strange but same logic working without master page,and  these two text boxes are not defined in master page, but i also gave try to Page.Master.FindControl()

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that, with the master page, your controls are now required to be placed in the `ContentPlaceHolder` controls.

> The FindControl method can be used to access a control whose ID is not
>   available at design time. The method searches only the page's
>   immediate, or top-level, container; it does not recursively search for
>   controls in naming containers contained on the page. To access
>   controls in a subordinate naming container, call the FindControl
>   method of that container.

You now need to recursively search through the controls to find your `TextBox` controls from the `PreviousPage`.  You can see [an example of that here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/06/recursive-pagefindcontrol.html). Also noted on that site, you can get the control by its full `UniqueID`, which in your case will work via:

```
TextBox nametextpb = (TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBox1")
```

**EDIT:** Figured it couldn't hurt to include the code I used to locate the `UniqueID` of the target control.

In Page_Load:

```
var ids = new List<string>();
BuildControlIDListRecursive(PreviousPage.Controls, ids);
```

And the method definition:

```
private void BuildControlIDListRecursive(ControlCollection controls, List<string> ids)
{
    foreach (Control c in controls)
    {
        ids.Add(string.Format("{0} : {2}", c.ID, c.UniqueID));
        BuildControlIDListRecursive(c.Controls, ids);
    }
}
```

Then just locate your control from the ids list.

Comment: ContentPlaceHolder ph1 = (ContentPlaceHolder)PreviousPage.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1"); and than applied same logic and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`(TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("TextBox1");` must have returned `null`, which means that the control was not found.

Try using `Page.Master.FindControl()` instead.